# function' object is not subscriptable", 'occurred at index 0'

Tags: typeerror

I have a dataframe (maple) that, amongst others, has the columns 'THM', which is filled with float64 and 'Season_index', which is filled with int64. The 'THM' column has some missing values, and I want to fill them using the following function:

```
def fill_thm(cols):

 THM = cols[0]
 Season_index = cols[1]

 if pd.isnull[THM]:
    if Season_index == 1:
        return 10
    elif Season_index == 2:
        return 20
    elif Season_index == 3:
        return 30
    else:
        return 40
 else:
    return THM
```

Then, to apply the function I used

```
maple['THM']= maple[['THM','Season_index']].apply(fill_thm,axis=1)
```

But I am getting the ("'function' object is not subscriptable", 'occurred at index 0') error. Anyone has any idea why? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def fill_thm(THM, S_i):

 if pd.isnull[THM]:
    if S_i == 1:
        return 10
    elif S_i == 2:
        return 20
    elif S_i == 3:
        return 30
    else:
        return 40
 else:
    return THM
```

And apply with:

```
maple.loc[:,'THM'] = maple[['THM','Season_index']].apply(lambda row: pd.Series((fill_thm(row['THM'], row['Season_index']))), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
def fill(cols):
Age = cols[0]
Pclass=cols[1]

if pd.isnull['Age']:

    if Pclass==1:
        return 37
    elif Pclass==2:
        return 30
    else:
        return 28

else:
    return Age

train[:,'Age'] = train[['Age','Pclass']].apply(fill,axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, when you use apply on a specific column, you need not to specify axis=1.

second, if you are using pandas 0.22, just upgrade to 0.24. It solves all the issues with apply on Dataframes.